# Toggle Class With Font Awesome Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, font-awesome

I have multiple buttons, when a like button is clicked I would like the font awesome icon to switch as well, however, the way I have it set up the font awesome icon just disappears, but I can see the class change. Not sure where to go from here.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $('#like' + this.id).toggleClass("fa-regular fa-thumbs-up");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/317f6467e2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="like-button btn" id="1">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-thumbs-up" id="like1"></i>
    </button>

<button class="like-button btn" id="2">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-thumbs-up" id="like2"></i>
    </button>
```

Comment: You need to give it another icon to show.   `fa-regular` is a style not an icon.  eg `.toggleClass("fa-thumbs-up fa-thumbs-down")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change icon/style just add other class to `toggleClass` like:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    $('#like'+this.id).toggleClass("fa-solid fa-thumbs-up fa-regular fa-thumbs-up");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/317f6467e2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="like-button btn" id="1">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-thumbs-up" id="like1"></i>
</button>

<button class="like-button btn" id="2">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-thumbs-up" id="like2"></i>
</button>
```